# UITableView won't appear until a scrolling action

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, afnetworking

I have already made this kind of thing maybe one hundred times but, this time I'm so disturbed:

I have an UITableView with custom UITableViewCell which loads a picture via AFNetworking [-setImageWithURLRequest:]; and when I run the app, the content of the tableview doesn't appear.
If I wait, 8 seconds later, the content appears but if I made an interaction like scrolling, the content appears immediately. So strange.

I already tried to solve the issue with this article: http://blog.slaunchaman.com/2011/08/14/cocoa-touch-circumventing-uitableviewcell-redraw-issues-with-multithreading/ but without success.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried [table reloadData];

Comment: It's already done ;-) I see (via NSLog) the UITableView is build (datasource) but I don't see anything...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you are updating your table's contents off the main thread (UI thread), without seeing any code this would be my best guess.

Comment: You're right. I update via a delegate method on the AFNetworking block. Thank you so much...!